# wrong day is returned in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I was building a custom DateTime picker. And I encountered an error when using the getDay function in javascript. It is described as following

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(1998,9,17);
var day= d.getDay(); 
console.log(day); //returns day 6(which is day saturday in javascript)
```

but when I Google `17/09/1998` it returns Thursday(which is day 4). Is Google is returning the wrong value

Comment: The `.setFullYear()` function takes only one argument. *edit* oh no it doesn't, wow learn something every day

Comment: `9` in Javascript is October. `9` everywhere else is September.

Comment: Ah but months are numbered from 0 in all date methods.

Comment: @Pointy the other two are optional if you read it here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods_set.asp

Comment: in javascript month starts from 0 to 11, like @Tyler Roper said... 9 is Oct in JS not Sept

Comment: @KarthikGanesan That's really strange since date value (here 17) does *not* start with 0. Not consistent.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone sometimes I wonder if JavaScript were not deliberately designed to improve Stackoverflow rep scores

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone check this link... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/179286/139504

Comment: @KarthikGanesan even so I would tend to consistently count days from 0 as well. We are programmers and used to do so.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone well probably because each month has own date count and validating it won't be that feasible where as list of month is a constant array of 12 values.